# Magento 2 how add extension attribute to order item

Tags: magento2, sales-order, extension-attributes, sales-order-item

I need to save the extension attribute for Order item. I have tried using plugin with below code, but it is not working for me. I have placed a log inside the method but the method is not working.

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="order_item_extension_attr" type="Vendor\CustomModule\Plugin\Model\Test"/>
</type>

public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItem, 
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionInterface $extension = null
    ) {

}
```

How to save and get order item extension attribute?

**Edited:**
Used an observer after order saved, stored the order and item extension attributes in db. Which is working fine, but showing the order item values are not showing up in the order view page.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** If you want to use extension attribute then you must declare **extension** attribute at `app/code/YOurModule/{Modulename}/etc/extension_attributes.xml`.

**Create extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">
        <attribute code="{fieldname}" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Assume that field type is varchar/text.

**2.** Create after plugin on `save()` method of `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` while save Order using `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface:save` method.

Comment: Hi @Amit 
Thank you for your response. In database the extension attributes are saving correctly but when view the order, the order item extension attributes are not showing the values. Please adivse.

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve orders' items, you are indirectly calling the **getList** method of *OrderItemRepositoryInterface*. That's where you have to put your plugin.

Plugin declaration in di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface">
     <plugin name="vendor_module_order_item_extension_attribute" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderItem\OrderItemRepository" />
 </type>
```

The afterGetList plugin method, where you provide the actual extension attributes data (in my case in a *extra_data* container)

```
 /**
     * @param OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderItemSearchResultInterface $searchResult
     * @return OrderItemSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function afterGetList(
        OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject,
        OrderItemSearchResultInterface $searchResult
    ): OrderItemSearchResultInterface
    {
        $orderItems = $searchResult->getItems();
        foreach ($orderItems as &$item) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->myOrderItemExtensionFactory->create();
            $this->myOrderItemExtensionResource->load($extensionAttributes, $item->getItemId(), 'entity_id');
            $item->getExtensionAttributes()->setExtraData($extensionAttributes);
        }
        return $searchResult;
    }
```

Comment: $this->myOrderItemExtensionResource ?

Answer (score -1):

add below plugin to your `di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="get_order_comment" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Yourplugin"/>
</type>
```

Now create below plugin here

**Vendor\Module\Plugin\Yourplugin**

```
class Yourplugin {

    protected $_orderExtensionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory $orderExtensionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_orderExtensionFactory = $orderExtensionFactory;
    }

    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $orderExtension = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->_orderExtensionFactory->create();

        $comment = {write the logic to get the comment. e.g. $order->getComment()}
        $orderExtension->setComment($comment);

        $order->setExtensionAttributes($orderExtension);

        return $order;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. But I have asked for order item level only, for order its working fine.