# Adding an Extension Attribute to Sales Order Items - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento-community, best-practice, extension-attributes

I have created some custom attributes for products and using these attributes in **order view** in customer account **orders** section. I have deleted few products. When I view the customer orders, it gives exception because the custom attributes data does not save in `sales_order_items` table. For this I decided to create **`extension attributes`** to save the custom attributes data in `sales_order_items` entity. I have done the below steps so far but could not able to fetch the custom attributes data in **orders view** section in customer account.

Step-1 ***Vendor\Module\registration.php***

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step-2 ***Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

Step-3 ***Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="extension_attribute_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AddExtensionAttributePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Step-4 ***Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">
        <attribute code="order_items_extension_attributes" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Step-5 ***Vendor/Module/Plugin/AddExtensionAttributePlugin.php***

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class AddExtensionAttributePlugin
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory */
    protected $orderExtensionFactory;

    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionFactory */
    protected $orderItemExtensionFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory $orderExtensionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionFactory $orderItemExtensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory $orderExtensionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionFactory $orderItemExtensionFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderExtensionFactory = $orderExtensionFactory;
        $this->orderItemExtensionFactory = $orderItemExtensionFactory;
    }


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $subject
     * @param $resultOrder
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterPlace( \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $subject, $resultOrder) {
        foreach ($resultOrder->getItems() as $orderItem) {
            $extensionAttributes = $orderItem->getExtensionAttributes();
            if (!($extensionAttributes && $extensionAttributes->getOrderItemsExtensionAttributes())) {
                /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtension $orderItemExtension */
                $orderItemExtension = $extensionAttributes
                    ? $extensionAttributes
                    : $this->orderItemExtensionFactory->create();
                if ($orderItem->getProduct()->getOrderItemsExtensionAttributes()) {
                    $orderItemExtension->setOrderItemsExtensionAttributes($orderItem->getProduct()->getOrderItemsExtensionAttributes());
                }
                $orderItem->setExtensionAttributes($orderItemExtension);
            }
        }
        $resultOrder->save();
        return $resultOrder;
    }
}
```

Step-6 ***Getting the extension attributes in orders view section***

```
$items = $order->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item){
    $extension_attribute_value = $item->getExtensionAttributes()->getOrderItemsExtensionAttributes();
}
```

Please any one can suggest if I am missing something?

Comment: Are you talking about my account >my order section

Comment: yes, after customer login

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
$items = $order->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item){
    $extension_attribute_value = $item->getProduct()->getOrderItemsExtensionAttributes();
}
```

But I dont think this is the fucntionality you wanted because if the product changes the value of this attribute it gonna change on the order. I believe you want to add the attribute value of this specific day of the purchase.

You can do that by creating a column on the `sales_order_item` and saving there the value of the product attribute with the use of plugin.

I think you didnt understand correctly the use of extention attribute. Here is how you create an extention attribute on the sales order item.  [Magento 2 how add extension attribute to order item](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318872/magento-2-how-add-extension-attribute-to-order-item)

Here is another good resource to understand the consept https://fooman.com/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html

Comment: I want to use deleted products custom attributes data in orders view section.

Comment: You need to persist this data somewhere and reference it from there. Because if you delete the product then all the attributes value will be deleted with it. Usually if its in the order item then add it in the sales_order_item table.

Comment: can I achieve it without creating column in the db?

Comment: The correct and easier way is in database, the more dysfunctional and harder is to save it in file or in some other rest api where you can easily create endpoints and create database tables but it still createing somewhere a database table.

Comment: what is the purpose of using extension attribute to save data to entity?

Comment: Its a naming convetion for service contract pattern as I know. Its make it easy in the future to reference it from API